# How to read a command output with pipe and scanf()?

Tags: c, linux, pipe

I need to be able to send the output of the GET command and store it into a variable inside my program, currently I'm doing it like this:

> GET google.com | ./myprogram

And receiving it in my program with the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  char *a = (char *) malloc (10000000);
  scanf("%[^\n]", a);
  printf("%s\n",a);

return 0;
}
```

The problem I have is that the scanf function stops at a new line, and I need to be able to store the whole paragraph output from GET.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You might look at the docs for `popen` and `read`

Comment: You ask `scanf` to read until newline (but not the newline itself). Perhaps you should use [`fread`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fread) instead? And don't allocate such a large block, read into a small buffer, and then have a larger that you reallocate as needed.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility: Does GET include the size information in the headers?  Could you use that to determine how much space to allocate, and how much data to read?  That's fiddly though, and requires reading the data in dribs and drabs.

More simply, consider using POSIX (and Linux) [`getdelim()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getdelim.html) (a close relative of [`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html)) and specify the delimiter as the null byte.  That's unlikely to appear in the `GET` output, so the whole content will be a single 'line', and `getdelim()` will allocate an appropriate amount of space automatically.  It also tells you how long the data was.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *buffer = 0;
    size_t buflen = 0;
    int length = getdelim(&buffer, &buflen, '\0', stdin);
    if (length > 0)
        printf("%*.*s\n", length, length, buffer);
    free(buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

scanf documentation says

> These functions return the number of input items  successfully 
>   matched and assigned, which can be fewer than provided for, or even
>   zero in the event of an early matching failure. The value EOF is
>   returned if the end of input is reached before  either the  first 
>   successful conversion or a matching failure occurs.  EOF is also
>   returned if a read error occurs, in which case the error indicator for
>   the  stream  (see ferror(3)) is set, and errno is set indicate the
>   error.

https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=scanf&sektion=3

Have you considered writing a loop that calls `scanf`, monitors its return value and breaks out if EOF

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following `readall()` function implemented in standard C:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char *readall(FILE *source, size_t *length)
{
    char   *data = NULL;
    size_t  size = 0;
    size_t  used = 0;
    size_t  n;

    /* If we have a place to store the length,
       we initialize it to zero. */
    if (length)
        *length = 0;

    /* Do not attempt to read the source, if it is
       already in end-of-file or error state. */
    if (feof(source) || ferror(source))
        return NULL;

    while (1) {

        /* Ensure there is unused chars in data. */
        if (used >= size) {
            const size_t  new_size = (used | 65535) + 65537 - 32;
            char         *new_data;

            new_data = realloc(data, new_size);
            if (!new_data) {
                /* Although reallocation failed, data is still there. */
                free(data);
                /* We just fail. */
                return NULL;
            }

            data = new_data;
            size = new_size;
        }

        /* Read more of the source. */
        n = fread(data + used, 1, size - used, source);
        if (!n)
            break;

        used += n;
    }

    /* Read error or other wonkiness? */
    if (!feof(source) || ferror(source)) {
        free(data);
        return NULL;
    }

    /* Optimize the allocation. For ease of use, we append
       at least one nul byte ('\0') at end. */
    {
        const size_t  new_size = (used | 7) + 9;
        char         *new_data;

        new_data = realloc(data, new_size);
        if (!new_data) {
            if (used >= size) {
                /* There is no room for the nul. We fail. */
                free(data);
                return NULL;
            }
            /* There is enough room for at least one nul,
               so no reason to fail. */
        } else {
            data = new_data;
            size = new_size;
        }
    }

    /* Ensure the buffer is padded with nuls. */
    memset(data + used, 0, size - used);

    /* Save length, if requested. */
    if (length)
        *length = used;

    return data;
}
```

It reads everything from the specified file handle (which can be a standard stream like `stdin` or a pipe opened via `popen()`) into a dynamically allocated buffer, appends a nul byte (`\0`), and returns a pointer to the buffer.  If not NULL, the actual number of characters read (so, not including the appended nul byte), is stored in the `size_t` pointed to by the second parameter.

You can use it to read binary data output by programs, say `dot -Tpng diagram.dot` or image converters, or even `wget -O -` output (getting data from specific URLs, text or binary).

You can use this for example thus:

```
int main(void)
{
    char    *src;
    size_t   len;

    src = readall(stdin, &len);
    if (!src) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error reading standard input.\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    fprintf(stderr, "Read %zu chars.\n", len);

    /* As an example, print it to standard output. */    
    if (len > 0)
        fwrite(src, len, 1, stdout);

    free(src);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The `readall()` function has two quirks: it allocates memory in roughly 131072-byte chunks (but could vary if `fread()` were to return short reads), and pads the buffer with 7 to 15 nul bytes.  (There are reasons why I like doing it this way, but it is all speculative and specific to the C libraries I tend to use, so it is not important.)

Although the ones used above work fine, you can change the `size_new` calculations if you prefer otherwise. Just make sure that they both are at least `used + 1`.